# Retrieve a slice of IDs recursively in GO

Tags: go, recursion, slice

```golang
type MenuItem struct {
        Id              int32       
        Type            string           
        SortOrder       int8        
        CategoryId      int32   
        Children        []*MenuItem 
    }
```

If you have this struct, and you have a slice of `[]MenuItem`. I would like to retrieve a slice only with `CategoryId` values. This looks like a recursive use case due to the `Children` but based on how append function for slices works, it looks a bit tricky. Any ideas? How would you do it?

The end result should be a slice of `[]int32`: [11, 1900, 12, 1300,...., 2090]

Comment: Shouldn't be that tricky, just ensure your recursive function returns the result of `append` so during any expansion reallocation the newer resized memory is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `append` do the hard work for you, handling memory expansion, and return its result during each recursive step:

```
func traverse(m *MenuItem) (r []int32) {

    if m == nil {
        return
    }

    r = append(r, m.CategoryId)

    for _, c := range m.Children {
        r = append(r, traverse(c)...)
    }

    return
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/8d0cyPMV0r6

Comment: Thx for your time! Sorry for late reply.